# Using a Nested For Loop to "Add" Two String Arrays With Number Values Together

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

I'm trying to make a program that takes x number of additives and turns them into a String based result. The reasoning for using String[ ] and not int[ ] is because some numbers are way too big for int/long (and we're not allowed to use BigInteger on this project), so we're sticking to String[ ] in this program. Also: all values in the String[ ] parameter are 25 zero's long, with the number replacing the last few of the zeros, as seen below.

For example: if you passed in a string array with the three values...

```
0000000000000000000000203

0000000000000000000000045

0000000000000000000000010
```

The method would condense it into a String[ ] with the value...

```
0000000000000000000000258
```

The difficult part is accounting for "carrying a number over", like in elementary algebra.
Below is what I've got so far

```
//Every array will be 25 digits long. Mostly zeroes with the numbers to add at the 
//end
public static final int ARRSIZE = 25;

public static void addStuff(String[] stuff)    {
    String[] result = new String[ARRSIZE];
    int[] holder = new int[ARRSIZE];
    String temp = "";
    int area = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < stuff.length; j++)
        {
            temp = stuff[j].substring(stuff[i].length() - 1-i, stuff[i].length()-i);
            area += Integer.parseInt(temp);
            if (area >= 10)
            {
                carry = area/10;
                holder[ARRSIZE - 1-i] = area%10;
                area = 0;
            }
            carry = 0;
        }
    }

    //TODO: Make int[] holder -> String[] result
    //Take result String[] to future method
}
```

What I'm trying to do with this code is to read the last element of each String[ ] element, turn it into an int to add down the line, and store the final number as a String[] (result) for later printing in a future method. I've always been pretty bad with nested for loops, so I figured this confusion would happen. So far, I've managed to get the logic down where I successfully add the rightmost column and store it in area, while carrying a number. From there on is where I'm lost.

Comment: What happens when you add two `ARRSIZE` numbers that are all 9s and have a carry, creating an `ARRSIZE+1`-sized number?

Comment: @ggorlen Are you suggesting I may get an out of bounds exception with this code? The highest number we're given in the assignment will not go over the 25-size, if that's what you're asking. It'll actually be 23 or 24 as the highest number given

Comment: OK, that's convenient. May I also ask: why are you returning `void`? How are you supposed to mutate the `String[] stuff` such that the result is returned? Is it supposed to turn into a string array with only one element and what happens to the extra space? Returning a `String` makes the most sense to me here.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm kinda not worrying about that right now. My current plan is to take what I get in this method and pass it on to another method. The future method will either output to console the math (goal of the assignment), or I'll change it to return back to the previous methods

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple solution, which you might have to adjust a bit so it fits your needs:

```
public static void addStuff(String[] stuff) {
    if (stuff.length != result.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("length does not match");
    }
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = stuff.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(result[i]) + Integer.parseInt(stuff[i]) + carry;
        carry = temp / 10;
        result[i] = String.valueOf(temp % 10);
    }
}
```

This adds the given String array to a global result array, defined like this:

```
private static final String[] result = "0000000000000000000000000".split("");
```

If you call it with the numbers you provided you can use it this way:

```
addStuff("0000000000000000000000203".split(""));
addStuff("0000000000000000000000045".split(""));
addStuff("0000000000000000000000010".split(""));
System.out.println(String.join("", result));
```

The result will be:

```
0000000000000000000000258
```

Hope that helps. Of course you should do some more exception handling, but this is just a little example to show you how you could solve your problem.